# Oracle query to find a Customer ID which was present in last two months

Tags: oracle

I have customer records of past 6 months in DB.

Currently I have column(TRNX_CREATED_DATE) to identify when was the transaction done.

Below is the query I used to get customer records for one month of period

```
select distinct(CN_NUMBER),ACCOUNT_NUMBER,TRNX_CREATED_DATE from TRANSACTION_REPORTS 
where TRNX_CREATED_DATE>=add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
```

With this query I am able to get customer records of last one month. Am not sure how to get customers who are newly added in this month or who were present in last two months or customers who were present in last month but were dropped off from this month.

But now I want to write three separate queries to do below functionalities

1. Customer who did a transaction in this month and as well as in previous month.
2. Customer who did a transaction in this month and but not in previous month.
3. Customer who haven't done a transaction in this month and but did a transaction    in previous month.

Please Suggest.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please include information on what you tried so far.

Comment: I have updated with additional info, plz suggest.

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do so; in the following I try to give a readable solution.
This solves the first problem:

```
select CN_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,TRNX_CREATED_DATE
from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t
/* a transaction in this month */
where trunc(last_day(t.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(sysdate)) 
  /* and a transaction in the previous month */
  and exists( select 1
              from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t2
              where t2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = t.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                and trunc(last_day(t2.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)))
             )
```

The second one is very similar, you only need a bit of boolean logics:

```
select CN_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,TRNX_CREATED_DATE
from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t
/* a transaction in this month */
where trunc(last_day(t.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(sysdate))
  /* no transactions in the previous month */
  and NOT exists(
                  select 1
                  from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t2
                  where t2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = t.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                    and trunc(last_day(t2.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)))
                 )
```

The third one, where you simply have the exchange the conditions:

```
select CN_NUMBER,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,TRNX_CREATED_DATE
from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t
/* a transaction in the previous month */
where trunc(last_day(t.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)))
  /* no transactions in this month */
  and NOT exists(
                  select 1
                  from TRANSACTION_REPORTS t2
                  where t2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = t.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                    and trunc(last_day(t2.TRNX_CREATED_DATE)) = trunc(last_day(sysdate))
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej, The above queries solved my requirement.